# How to implement Commerce USPS Shipping?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have installed the following modules:

1. [Commerce Shipping module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping) (7.x-2.2)

   Shipping UI
2. [Commerce USPS module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_usps) (7.x-2.0)
3. [Commerce Physical Product](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_physical) (7.x-1.x-dev)

Checkout without shipping is working fine.Now in checkout settings I have enabled shipping service and info.

I am able to see USPS shipping method config and rules which are set to default (for now). I tried using different rules but can't see any shipping method in the checkout screen.

I have set production account username and url of the USPS.com (this probably isn't the problem).

I want to know step by step procedure to configure the shipping method and rules to add USPS shipping service.

I have 3 products types from which only one will have shipping service,I can see "Shipping" line item type but how to implement it to the product type so that shipping is shown on the checkout screen or is it optional?

Comment: I am getting this error on the checkout shipping page, "Undefined property: stdClass::$shipping_rates in commerce_shipping_rate_apply() (line 212 of /sites/all/modules/commerce_shipping/commerce_shipping.rules.inc)".

Answer (score 1):

Have a lok at the [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_usps/tree/README.txt) that comes with the [Commerce USPS](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_usps) module, here is the content of it:

> ## About this module
>
> Commerce USPS module provides shipping calculations from the USPS
> WebTools API
>
> ## Dependencies
>
> This module depends on the Commerce module
> (http://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).
>
> In addition, the following modules are required:
>
> - Commerce Physical - http://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_physical -  this module is used to define the physical properties (weight and  dimensions) of each product. This information is necessary to
>   determine  a shipping estimate.
> - Commerce Shipping (7.x-2.x) -  http://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping - this provides the
>   infrastructure for Commerce UPS to fully integrate with the Commerce
>   module.
>
> ## Installation
>
> 1. Install and enable the module and all dependencies (be sure to use  the latest versions of everything). Add dimensions and weight fields
>    (new field types via the Commerce Physical module) to all shippable
>    product types. Populate dimensions and weight fields for all products.
> 2. Configure the "Shipping service" checkout pane so that it is on the  "Shipping" page. The "Shipping service" checkout pane MUST be on a
>    later  page than the "Shipping information" pane.
>    (admin/commerce/config/checkout)
> 3. Configure the USPS settings  (admin/commerce/config/shipping/methods/usps/edit). You'll need to
>    create USPS WebTools account and obtain a username via
>    https://secure.shippingapis.com/registration/.
>
> ## Limitations
>
> Eventually, all of these limitations may be addressed. For now, be
> warned.
>
> 1. Single "Ship from" address for all products.
> 2. Doesn't ensure product dimensions are less than default package size  dimensions. In other words, if you have a product that is 1x1x20
>    (volume=20) and your default package size is 5x5x5 (volume=125), even
>    though the product won't physically fit in the box, these values will
>    be  used to calculate the shipping estimate.
> 3. Doesn't play Tetris. For example, if you have an order with 14  products with a combined volume of 50 and your default package size
>    has  a volume of 60, the shipping estimate will be for a single box
>    regardless of if due to the packaging shape they don't actually fit in
>    the box.
> 4. Doesn't limit the weight of packages. If you're trying to ship a box  full of lead that weighs 600lbs, this module will let you
>    (instead of  breaking the order into more packages).
> 5. Doesn't account for packing material. If you need to account for  packing material, then you may want to adjust product dimensions
>    accordingly.
>
> ## Methodology
>
> Calculating estimated shipping costs is a tricky business, and it can
> get really complicated really quickly. Knowing this, we purposely
> designed this module with simplicity in mind. Here's how it works:
>
> 1. Every order must contain at least one package.
> 2. The number of packages is determined by calculating the total volume  of all products in the order, dividing by the volume of the
>    default  package size, and rounding up.
> 3. The weight of each package is determined by dividing the total weight  of all products in the order by the number of packages.
>
> If you need custom functionality, you have several options:
>
> 1. Determine if it is something that can be generalized to suit a number  of users and submit it via the issue queue as a suggestion for
>    inclusion  in this module.
> 2. Hire one of the maintainers to create a custom module that interfaces  with Commerce UPS to add your custom functionality.
> 3. Break open a text editor and start coding your own custom module.

Apart from that, the module's project page contains this extra info:

> Please refer to the README.txt file for additional information about how this module works and how to set it up.
>
> 1. Install and enable the module and all dependencies.
> 2. Add dimensions and weight fields (new field types via the Commerce Physical module) to all shippable product types.
> 3. Populate dimensions and weight fields for all products.
> 4. Configure the USPS settings (admin/commerce/config/shipping/methods/usps/edit). You'll need to create USPS Web Tools account and obtain a username https://secure.shippingapis.com/registration/ and call USPS to have the account moved into production (tell them you are using 3rd party software).

Comment: Yes, I have already read this documentation and also have Physical module installed. It explains about Physical module ,USPS config settings etc, But it does not explain how to actually setup the shipping method and rules (using the default method is not showing up on checkout screen). I wanted to know those steps.